# Assigning an array creates a pointer or copies an array? (Solidity)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, memory

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity^0.4.16;

contract Test {

    struct SomeData {
        address[] users;
    }

    address[] nullArray;
    mapping(uint => SomeData) SomeDataList;

    function insertData(uint number) {
        SomeDataList[number] = SomeData({
            users : nullArray
        });

        SomeDataList[number].users.push(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

In `insertData` function I initialize a new structure and assign `nullArray` to `users` field (`users` now store a copy of `nullArray` or a pointer to it?). After that, I push some data to this structure and I'm not sure whether the global variable `nullArray` will be affected or not.

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake Sorry, just misclicked because of browser lag)) answer is great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> users now store a copy of nullArray or a pointer to it?

It will create an independent copy. As I understand since both `nullArray` and `SomeDataList` are state variables there will be two independent copies.

It's mentioned in the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location) that,

> assignments between storage and memory and **also to a state variable**
>   (**even from other state variables**) always create an independent copy.

hence,

> I push some data to this structure and I'm not sure whether the
>   global variable nullArray will be affected or not

`nullArray` will not be affected.

**UPDATE**

I tried your code with some additional functions in [Remix-IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org) as follow,

```
pragma solidity^0.4.16;

contract Test {

    struct SomeData {
        address[] users;
    }

    address[] nullArray;
    mapping(uint => SomeData) SomeDataList;

    function insertData(uint number) {
        SomeDataList[number] = SomeData({
            users : nullArray
        });

        SomeDataList[number].users.push(msg.sender);
    }


    function getusers(uint number) constant returns(address []){
        return SomeDataList[number].users;
    }

    function getNullArray() constant returns(address[]){
        return nullArray;
    }

    function pushNullArray(address addr){
        nullArray.push(addr);
    }

}
```

And `nullArray` and `SomeDataList` acted as two different variables. Here are the function call results after calling `pushNullArray(address addr)` and `insertData(uint number)` with some arbitrary values.

[image]

They were not the same.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It creates a copy. Even though `nullArray` & `users` here are storage reference types, assignment to state variables always does a copy.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour